# How to get a image's indexpath in CollectionView in TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, indexpath

In my program, each row of TableView has a Collection, each CollectionView has several Images. I have set `Tag` and `UITapGestureRecognizer` for the image in the `collectionView(_:, cellForItemAt:)` method, but `Tag` can only represent the position of the image in the CollectionView. How do I know the position of the clicked image in the Table and pass the row of TableView and the row of Collection to `UITapGestureRecognizer(target:, action: #selector())` method?

Comment: Give a indepath.row of tableView into collectionview tag. then you can easily get the tag from collectionview didselect method.

Comment: Do not use tap gesture recognizer on collectionView. Use didSelectItemAtIndexPath instead. Write a protocol in collectionView and confirm to methods in your tableView, every time user taps on cell in collectionView trigger the delegate with the collectionView instance and its indexPath of cell to tableView. Now in order to find the tableView cell holding the collectionView use indexPathsForRows method of tableView that should help. Or you can go back to logic of setting tag to collectionView which will represent its indexPath in tableView and rather returning collectionView return its tag

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I do not want to click on the entire cell, I just want to click on the picture inside the cell.

Comment: @jake-to : I presume that each image is in individual cell of `UICollectionView` hence u can make use of `UICollectionView` `didSelectItem` delegate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
func imageTapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: tableView)
    let ipath: IndexPath? = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)
    let cellindex: UITableViewCell? = tableView.cellForRow(at: ipath ?? 
 IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let pointTable :CGPoint = sender.convert(sender.bounds.origin, to: self.upComing_tblView)

        let indexpath = self.upComing_tblView.indexPathForRow(at: pointTable)
```

you can find table view cell row here